# Size of a List in an array of lists, Standard libraries C++

Tags: arrays, list, visual-c++

I have a Array of lists declared as the following

```
std::array<std::list<Bot*>, 21> bots = *game->getGSM()->getSpriteManager()->getBots();
```

where the referenced method returns the object of that type (an array of lists of bots) however when I try to get the size and append it to a wstringstream (its a windows app) via the following method

```
    wss << bots[i].size;
```

I get the following error

Error   2   error C3867: 'std::list>::size': function call missing argument list; use '&std::list>::size' to create a pointer to member

getting the address of the list by changing the line to

```
wss << &bots[i].size;
```

I get the following error
Error   2   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

I get the feeling that I am missing something very basic for C++ that I should know, and am forgetting at the time, as I have not actively coded in C++ in years.

Comment: change wss << bots[i].size; to wss << bots[i].size();

Comment: yup, the kind of thing I thought I was already doing, whoops, thanks, always helps to get an extra pair of eyes.